# How to fix the two version of jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://labellaintimates.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://labellaintimates.com/wp-content/themes/labella/jquery.js"></script>
```

There is a jquery conflict, can you please help me to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you remove one.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 4):

I think what's happening here is that WordPress is loading it's own version of jQuery, and you're also loading one manually from your theme.

In your functions file, include this script:

```
function my_scripts_method() { // Creates the my_scripts_method function
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // Deregisters the built-in version of jQuery
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/YOUR-JS-PATH.js', false, null, true); // Registers your javascript file
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Activates the jQuery script
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method'); // Tells WordPress to run the my_scripts_method function
```

I suspect that your theme (or a plugin) may already be registering your local jQuery file, though, and simply failing to deregister the one WordPress includes, so you should dig around a little bit to make sure you're not calling the same file twice.

**Update -** You can find a bit more detail in this here: http://gomakethings.com/jquery-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You only need one. They are both the same thing, but possibly different versions. If one of your scripts break after removing one, then your script probably doesn't work with that particular version, but in most causes should work just fine.